# How to handle common nested data in JSON? Which structure is best?

Tags: json, api, rest, api-design

I basically have an array of objects with an attribute (for example, shirtSize. and shirtSize can have values like M, L, XL). My client (frontend) is consuming this response and would like to display this list as a row item with a label (= shirtSize). And on frontend there is an icon on each row item when clicked on it displays exact dimensions (like height, width, etc).

Note: Please assume these sizes(L, XL, X) are the only sizes available across all the brands and they have the same dimensions across all brands.

To achieve this I have two JSON types of structures and am confused to choose which one to pick over.

Structure 1:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "brand": "queen",
            "color": "black",
            "size": "X",
            "height: 24,
            "breadth": 35
        },
        {
            "brand": "jack",
            "color": "green",
            "size": "L",
            "height: 22,
            "breadth": 30
        },
        {
            "brand": "yeo",
            "color": "blue",
            "size": "XL",
            "height: 29,
            "breadth": 39
        },
        {
            "brand": "tero",
            "color": "pink",
            "size": "L",
            "height: 22,
            "breadth": 30
        },
        ... // more objects
    ]
}
```

Structure 2:

```
{
    "size": {
        "X": {
            "height": 24,
            "breadth": 35
        },
        "L": {
            "height: 22,
            "breadth": 30
        },
        "XL": {
            "height: 29,
            "breadth": 39
        }
    }
    "data": [
        {
            "brand": "queen",
            "color": "black",
            "size": "X",

        },
        {
            "brand": "jack",
            "color": "green",
            "size": "L",

        },
        {
            "brand": "yeo",
            "color": "blue",
            "size": "XL",

        },
        {
            "brand": "tero",
            "color": "pink",
            "size": "L",

        },
        ... // more objects
    ]
}
```

Share your thoughts on which structure is better and why

Answer (score 0):

First one

In the second one, you're supposing each brand has the same sizes. An L in brand A can be quite different from a L in brand B. Even in the same brand, to clothes can be quite different.

If you don't want to manage each item size (to save some network), I would at least add a dimension to sizes by specifying the brand ( L, brand A => x, y | L, brand B => x1, y1 | ....)

Comment: Please assume these sizes(i.e L, XL, X) are the only sizes available across all the brands and they have the same dimensions across all brands. I just kept the key name as a brand to just populate the data for example.
PS: I have updated the question with above assumption

Answer (score 0):

Second One.

Its because structure well organized there is no unnecessary data you make it few by parsing Size as a main object and adding height and breadth which is logical.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your response must be that which need less transormations on the front side. Adapt it to be as easily as possible to understand it. By other hand, I like more the second one because you dont repeat data and is smaller to transfer it and it is more readable.